# Laravel Internal Server vs XAMPP/WAMP Server?

Tags: php, laravel, server, xampp, laravel-artisan

Is there any benefit of using Laravel Internal server (php artisan serve) over XAMPP or WAMP server? Because I feel it uncomfortable to keep running a command-prompt for the command 'php artisan serve'.

Comment: the `php artisan serve` is here if you don't want to set up a web server.  and you want to quickly test your Laravel application. but you may use a web server such as Apache or Nginx to serve your Laravel applications.

Answer (score 1):

php artisan serve is indeed just a wrapper around php -S .. it's for a quick test of things without having to set up a full web stack, decidely not for production use.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Homestead is preferred more than Internal Server or XAMPP/WAMP because you can setup a similar environment as your production server and if you're using more than one computer or more than one person, you can share the configuration.

This method requires a little more configuration but the documentation is very good. 
You won't have to remember to keep the terminal window open when you use it, but you'll still have to remember to keep the virtual machine running.

[Laravel Homestead Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)